# Purple and black screen and no logo before login screen

Tags: boot, 18.04

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo laptop. A purple then black screen appears before logging in, after this the OS works fine. Why doesn't the Ubuntu logo appear when booting? The login screen is OK. My graphics is AMD Radeon Stoney Ridge.
How to set the default Lenovo logo instead of ubuntu missing logo? There is no such option in my laptop's BIOS. 
Laptop boot time is 20 seconds. I installed plymouth themes but after a few restarts the logo doesn't appear anymore. I have put several themes but with  the same result.

Answer (score 0):

With new version 18.04.4 the lenovo logo appear and after that ubuntu logo before logging in. The boot time is faster than previous version almost 10 seconds.